# Python Flask переход на другую страницу

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, flask

Пишу небольшое веб приложение на Python Flask. Необходимо, чтобы оно работало в локальной сети. Когда я открываю http://127.0.0.1:49555/, используется файл index.html. Как сделать так, чтобы после выполнения функции CreateGameBtnF() у меня начал использоваться файл leader.html? Заранее спасибо

PS функция CreateGameBtnF() вызывается после нажатия на кнопку.

Вот Python код:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, redirect
import json
    
app =  Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/creategame', methods=['POST'])
def creategame():
    print(request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', request.remote_addr))
    return redirect(render_template('leader.html'))

@app.route('/connect', methods=['POST'])
def connect():
    print('asdasdsad')
    return 'Подключено'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=49555, debug=True)
```

Вот JS код:

```
function CreateGameBtnF() {
    let response = fetch("/creategame", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            e: 's'
        }),
    });
}

function ConnectBtnF() {
    let response = fetch("/connect", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: 's'
        }),
    });
}
```

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите контентом из leader.html заменить текущий контент страницы?

Comment: @alex, да, именно это, извините что так долго

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# ajax
<script>
        $(function() {
          $('form').submit(function(e) {
            var $form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
              type: $form.attr('method'),
              url: $form.attr('action'),
              data: $form.serialize()
          }).done(function(response) {
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(response)
            $('#data').html(json.data);
            console.log('success');
        }).fail(function() {
          console.log('fail');
      });
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
      });
</script>

# форма запроса данных
<form action="/get_data" method="post" id="finduser" name="form">
...
<button type="submit" name="finduser" value="Validate">Поиск</button>

# отображение данных с помощью ajax
<section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex bd-highlight">
        <div id="data"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
# обработка данных и возврат на страницу
@app.route('/get_data', methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    lst = search_user(request.form['name'].lower())
    return json.dumps({'data': render_template('response.html', lst=lst, len=range(0, len(lst)))})

# response.html
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    {% if lst == 'empty' %}
    {% else %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for i in len %}
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 20rem; height: 20,5rem; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <strong>{{lst[i]['l_name']}} {{lst[i]['f_name']}} {{lst[i]['middle']}}</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

[черпал отсюда](https://hruks.ru/2016/03/25/ajax-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-flask/)