# Flask: как взаимодействовать с базой данных

Tags: javascript, python, sqlite, flask

Изучаю фласк, хочу сделать страничку с кнопкой, которая генерирует эльфийские имена. Я написал код на питоне, который берет два слова из txt словаря Квеньи и выдает имя. Я хочу переписать весь этот код на js, чтобы привязать его к html кнопке, но я не знаю, каким образом сделать обращение из js к словарю или sqlite db.

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки осуществлялся запрос в дб и оттуда вытаскивались бы два случайных значения. Это возможно? Или мне нужно иначе к этому всему подходить (не знаю, скопипастить весь словарь в script.js)? Спасибо!

Comment: А зачем вам Flask и бд? Если хотите разобраться с Flask лучший туториал [здесь](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database) (правда англоязычный)

Comment: @SergBocharov генератор имени - это часть веб-приложения, которое я делаю ради изучения flask. Глобально - это инструмент, помогающий вести d&d5e игры. Часть этого инструмента - создание случайных персонажей, которым нужно имя. Помимо того, что мне нужна бд для словаря эльфийских слов, предполагается, что crud будет частью приложения - то есть, что пользователь сможет сохранять и вызывать сохраненных персонажей.

Спасибо за туториал!

Comment: @SergBocharov но в данном случае, мне нужно решить вот эту локальную проблему - как переписать python код, который обращается к txt словарю в js код: нужно ли мне сделать дб, чтобы js обращался к ней за словами или мне прям впихнуть весь словарь в script, или лучше сделать что-то еще.

Comment: посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1175114/234134, там и `flask` и `ajax`, скорее всего подойдёт, главное разобраться

Comment: Вообще есть перевод всего добра, которое привел @SergBocharov, здесь https://habr.com/ru/post/346306/ - добротная вещь. Если нужно изучать фласк - то сюда. Со временем можно будет разобраться и применить полученные знания к своей задаче. Если нужно решить эту конкретную задачу и поскорее - то скопипастить весь словарь в script - недурная идея. Или следующим этапом вынести словать в data.json, положить в ту же папку с index.html и доставать с помощью ajax.

Comment: Зачем отредактировали вопрос? Если это ответ - надо было запостить в виде ответа, не возбраняется. Если вопрос про безопасность - задайте новый вопрос. Здесь некуда дальше дискуссию продолжать.

Comment: @mrEvgenX да, это был ответ. Подумал, может, кому пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

Cделал следующим образом все. Клиентская часть:

```
let adjList;
let nounList;

$( document ).ready(function(){
    $.get('/adjList', function(adjs){
        adjList = adjs;
    });
    $.get('/nounList', function(nouns){
        nounList = nouns;
    })
})
```

Flask часть:

```
@app.route('/adjList', methods=['GET'])
def adj():
    return jsonify(open('adjList.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines())


@app.route('/nounList', methods=['GET'])
def noun():
    return jsonify(open('nounList.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines())
```

Едиственный минус этого всего состоит в том, что у меня теперь есть линк с огромным списком, на который, теоретически, можно случайно наткнуться. Не знаю, насколько это компрометурет безопасность.