# Как подставить значения в шаблон при обращении через ajax?

Tags: python, django

У меня в приложении django есть страница html (ее код не потребуется), вот, при нажатии на кнопку `подписчики` идет обращение к серверу через ajax, который вернёт html код для вставки.
Вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы при обращении к серверу, на стороне последнего читался и возвращался `html` файл, учитывая, что внутри есть параметры?

Сам `html`:

```
{% load my_filter %}



<div class="block_author">


    <a href="">

        <!-- аватарка -->
        <img class="img_avatar" src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{{ q.avatar }}">

    </a>



    <!-- текстовая информация -->
    <div class="block_info" href="">

        <!-- ссылка на профиль автора -->
        <a href="">
            
            <!-- имя -->
            <h4 class="name item">{{ q.name }}</h4>

            <!-- рейтинг -->
            <span class="respect item"><i class="fas fa-award"></i>{{ list_respect|MF_list_index:forloop.counter0 }}</span>
        
        </a>


        <!-- кнопка подписаться -->
        <a class="subscribe mimi_button" href="">Подписаться</a>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: может будет полезно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1175114/234134

Comment: Так же, как с обычным запросом - вызвать render, вернуть результат.