# Как получить переменную из шаблона? Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Есть шаблон flask, по нажатию на кнопку он показывает модальное окно, предлагает поменять имя клиента.
Вопрос, как можно получить переменную db.id, чтобы дальше использовать ее для обновления записи в базе данных? Спасибо.

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
    <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
      <div class="chartjs-size-monitor" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; pointer-events: none; visibility: hidden; z-index: -1;">
        <div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1;">
          <div style="position:absolute;width:1000000px;height:1000000px;left:0;top:0"></div></div><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1;">
        <div style="position:absolute;width:200%;height:200%;left:0;top:0;text-align:center;"></div></div></div>

      <div class="table-responsive" style="text-align:center;">
        <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Статус</th>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>IP-адрес</th>
              <th>Имя</th>
              <th>Подтверждение</th>
              <th>Время получения</th>
              <th>Редактирование</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for db in database %}
            <tr>
              <td><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=db.img) }}" /></td>
              <td>{{ db.id }}</td>
              <td>{{ db.ip }}</td>
              <td>{{ db.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ db.confirm }}</td>
              <td>{{ db.time }}</td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#set_name{{ db.id }}">Изменить имя</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </main>

{% for db in database %}
  <div class="modal fade" id="set_name{{ db.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="settings" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Изменить имя у клиента</h4>
      </div>
      <form method="post">
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Введите новое имя для клиента с ID<br> {{ db.id }}</label><br>
            {{ set_name.name_client(class="form-control", placeholder="Введите имя для клиента") }}
          </div>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          {{ set_name.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
          <button class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Откуда вы хотите получить эту переменную. В вопросе недостаточно информации

Comment: возможно это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1175114/234134 натолкнёт Вас на решение

Comment: По сабмиту формы `set_name` забрать переменную `db.id` (как она указана в вашей модели)

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел вариант, сделать скрытое поле для передачи данных, которые нужны, вопрос можно закрывать, всем спасибо